# App Inventor sharing files No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }

Tags: app-inventor

I'm a beginner at **App Inventor** and I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the `sharing` component. I'm trying to share a sound file but it gives me the following error:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }

The code is the following:

[image: Code that don't work]

I also tried the following things:
This doesn't work.

[image: trying some answers from other forums]

This reproduces the sound perfectly. That means that the picker works and the file exists.

[image]

I put a file in my root folder and it works but I want to send the file which was picked from the list which is in the following folder "/storage/sdcard0/MyDocuments/Downloads/app_inventor_1431867799168.mpeg".

[image]

I don't know where is the problem and I look in a lot of forums and none of the solutions solved my problem.

Thanks for your help.

PD: I just found that the downloaded files are stored in .MPEG format which it is a compressed format. It is possible that sharing function don't find any app that accept this type of format. If this is the problem please tell me what I have to do to make App Inventor to not change the original .mp3 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, problem solved as I said in the PD part the problem was that by default App Inventor stores the audio files in to MPEG format. This format is not recognized by whatsapp, gmail, etc...
Solution was to set a name to each file when I download them that ends with .mp3

With this extention the programs of my device recognize them and now I can share my audio files.

Thanks to everyone that was trying to solve this problem.